# Running PHP code using cron jobs

Tags: php, cron

I have some executable PHP code that I'm trying to implement using cron jobs. The page sends a couple emails. It works just fine when I type in the address into my URL bar and load the page (the url is akin to www.mysite.com/mypage.php)  but for some reason it doesn't work when I do it as part of a cron job. I have double checked the permissions and the file is executable, so that's not the issue. I am getting an email confirming that the cron job was completed, but the emails that are supposed to be sent by the program do not come through. Here is my code in  crontabs:

```
SHELL= /bin/bash/
HOME = / 
MAILTO = "mymail@gmail.com"
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /usr/share/nginx/html/mypage.php
```

Any idea why this might not be working?

---

EDIT ABOUT PERMISSIONS: Possibly relevant: I am editing cron jobs by typing 'sudo crontab -e'. I was able to successfully set up another cron job that just emails me text. However, I tried setting up another text-only-email cron job NOT in sudo (ie typing 'crontab -e') and that did not work. I didn't receive any emails. I also got an error when I typed 'crontab -e' about it not being able to read .nano_history and permission being denied but I was able to bypass that by pressing Enter

Comment: does it work properly from the command line if you run `/usr/bin/php /usr/share/nginx/html/mypage.php`

Comment: full error reporting and logging on

Comment: Sometimes command line PHP can be a different version or use a different php.ini than web-served PHP.

Comment: @BrianGlaz - no, it does not work. I have this at the top of my PHP file but am not sure where to look for the log: 
   ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(-1);

Comment: The problem is that the PHP command-line interpreter is not running, setup your environment to run it before create a cron job

Comment: @HemersonVarela thank for replying but can you tell me how to do that? I tried adding ${PATH_TO_PHP} before the path to the file but I got another error

Comment: what environment are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu through Digital Ocean

Comment: added an update about permissions, maybe relevant

Comment: are you calling any files in the php file?

Comment: @michael, thank you for your comment. I finally figured out it was because I was calling a file in the php file but the reference wasn't going through because it began with '../'. Thanks again

Comment: You're welcome! Good you got it working!

Answer (score 0):

Check to see that wget is installed on your server. it should be. Then use wget to call your program from the cron tab. This way you do not have to concern yourself with calling php from the command line.

```
wget http://999.999.99.9/hr/stats/send_stats.php?task=first
```